# How to fill the screen with DetailViewController

Tags: objective-c, ipad, xcode4.2, master-detail

I created a project using Master-Detail Application template but i don't need a MasterView. So i deleted Masterview files and codes but this time when i rotate the Simulator/Device in the left side of my main screen a black area stays. I want to stretch my Detail view to fill all the scren but i have no idea how to do. Can anyone please help? Thanks in advance

**Note:** My app needen NavigationController, firstly i tried SingleView template, but i couldn't push views on that template so i created my app in Master-Detail Application template..

Comment: just try with singleView template it's so easy .there are so many tutorial on navigation controller. google it.

Comment: I can push views modally but can't do it 'push' in single View mode. and i have googled really a lot..

Comment: but in single view what'e the need of push?

Comment: I need a navigation controller since my app has 5 different views, the first one is a login page, when i press login button i want to go to the second view and from some buttons inside those views navigate back/forward.. I have completed anything but my boss doesn't accept the black area when i rotate the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
        BNT_DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[[BNT_DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BNT_DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
     UINavigationController *detailNavigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];

     self.splitViewController = [[[UISplitViewController alloc] init] autorelease];
     self.splitViewController.delegate = detailViewController;
     self.splitViewController.viewControllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:detailNavigationController, nil];
     self.window.rootViewController = self.splitViewController;
     [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];


    BNT_DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[[BNT_DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BNT_DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
     navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];


       self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

This was the first appearance of the `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`of my ..AppDelegate.m but i changed it with below:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{

    self.window = [[[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]] autorelease];

    //define navigationController in ..AppDelegate.h 
    BNT_DetailViewController *detailViewController = [[[BNT_DetailViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"BNT_DetailViewController" bundle:nil] autorelease];
     navigationController = [[[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:detailViewController] autorelease];


       self.window.rootViewController = self.navigationController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I answered my own answer in case it may be helpful for someone who lives the same pains:)